# Konva - line doesnt touch the circle - gap between circle and line

Tags: javascript, css, konvajs

Im having problem with konva js. The line between circles doesnt touch them, the gap between circle and line is too big.

Also if the gap between circles is small or they just on the top of each other, the line is too big...

Playground:
https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-wood-douzq

[image: t]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `getConnectorPoints()` function you have `radius` variable that defines the offset between a circle and line. Just make it equal to the radius of the circle and you will have expected result:

```
const RADIUS = 10;

function getConnectorPoints(from, to) {
  const dx = to.x - from.x;
  const dy = to.y - from.y;
  let angle = Math.atan2(-dy, dx);

  return [
    from.x + -RADIUS * Math.cos(angle + Math.PI),
    from.y + RADIUS * Math.sin(angle + Math.PI),
    to.x + -RADIUS * Math.cos(angle),
    to.y + RADIUS * Math.sin(angle)
  ];
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/connected-dots-demo-1kkqc